# unable to remove movieclip itself from stage as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs6

I had a button, with that button a **movieclip** is called on the stage and it is working fine with the below script.
I just updated the script and it is now working fine with the removing of **movieclip** from the stage, but now the issue came with playing the **movieclip**. Now the **movieclip** is not playing well.

```
var btn: btn_Lemon = new btn_Lemon();
var mc: mc_lemon = new mc_lemon();

    addChild(btn);

    btn.x = 304.45;
    btn.y = 209.8;

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, login, false, 0, true);

    function login(event: MouseEvent): void {
    stage.addChild(mc);
    mc.x = 304.45;
    mc.y = 209.8;
    mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOver, false, 0, true);
}

function fadeOver(event: Event): void {

    if (event.currentTarget.currentFrame == 25) {
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOver);
        stage.removeChild(mc);
    }
}
```

What is going on please help somebody

Comment: How are you trying to remove the clip?

Comment: I was trying to remove it by placing this script at its last frame  `this.parent.removeChild(this);` but failed

Comment: Please don't add Code to comments. [edit] your question instead and add the changes you made to your code to it.

Comment: It looks like your original question has changed from a problem with removing a clip to now having a problem playing a clip. I suggest editing the title of this question. Even better would be to show how you solved you original problem, mark it as correct, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming it's a timeline you're trying to play inside lemon_mc and it's the play method that doesn't seem to run properly.
In my experience Flash can *sometimes* be a bit fickle with playing as I recall.

Here are some pointers for pushing the MC to play:

---

1. Force the a mc to play at the end of the

   ```
   function login(event: MouseEvent): void {
   stage.addChild(mc);
   mc.x = 304.45;
   mc.y = 209.8;
   mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOver, false, 0, true);
   mc.play();
   ```

   }
2. Simple add

   play();

at the first frame inside the movie clip you want to play.

3. Also if the playback is a bit fickle at certain scenarios you can define with code, then you can use a test:

   if (mc.isPlaying == false) {
     mc.play();
   }

As a beginner I found the as3 documentation from adobe to be easy to understand and apply. You might find some other properties to read or methods you can manipulate to force the play method:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html